# Having a yes/no input from user determine if the while loop continues

Tags: python, function, loops, input

I have read other questions with similar topics, but I just don't understand and none of them work. So here is my code, and what I need to do is have users input a number, then decide if they want to continue. Once they are done, I call a function that checks which number they have entered is the smallest number. The checking for the smallest number part is right, but I just cant get the yes/no input to work with the rest of the code. Please help!

```
listnum = []

def EnteringNum():
    done = False
    while not done:
        num = input("Enter a number!")
        listnum.append(num)
        con = raw_input("Do you wish to continue?")
        if con.startswith("n") or con.startswith("N"):
            exit()

def Smallest(listnum):
    lowest = listnum[0]
    for i in range(len(listnum)):
        if listnum[i] < lowest:
            lowest = listnum[i]
    print lowest

EnteringNum()
Smallest(listnum)
```

Comment: "I just don't understand" - well, what didn't you understand? What questions did you read? They should have explained exactly what do. We can point out the change you need to make - in fact, someone will probably do just that in a few minutes - but that probably won't fix your understanding or teach you to apply answers from similar questions to your problem.

Comment: You should state clearly what is happening when you run your code. I'm assuming that `exit()` is an error, but it would be a lot easier to write an answer if you said what was going wrong in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, of `exit()`, just put a `break`:

```
listnum = []

def EnteringNum():
    done = False
    while not done:
        num = input("Enter a number!")
        listnum.append(num)
        con = raw_input("Do you wish to continue?")
        if con.lower().startswith("n"):
            break

def Smallest(listnum):
    lowest = listnum[0]
    for i in range(len(listnum)):
        if listnum[i] < lowest:
            lowest = listnum[i]
    print lowest

EnteringNum()
Smallest(listnum)
```

Answer (score -1):

Running `exit()` will exit your entire program. If you just want to end the loop, you can change it to

```
def EnteringNum():
  listnum = []
  done = False
  while not done:
    num = input("Enter a number!")
    listnum.append(num)
    con = raw_input("Do you wish to continue?")
    if con.startswith("n") or con.startswith("N"):
        done = True
  return listunum
```

or you could get rid of the `if` clause with

```
con = raw_input('Do you wish to continue?')
done = con.startswith("n") or con.startswith("N")
```

since the `con.startswith....` returns a boolean. Once your `done` becomes `true`, it will end the loop.

Since we now initialize `listnum` in the function, we would call it

```
numbers = EnteringNum()
Smallest(numbers)
```

Comment: I don't think the global `listnum` was a part of the questioner's problem (though it's probably a bad idea from a design perspective). Other than mixing that in, this is a good answer!